# How to set position of the top svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Let's say we've got a very simple set up like below

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
            svg.attr("width", "100").attr("height", "100").style("border", "1px solid black");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What determines the position of the top svg element? How would it be possible to change it?

When you look up the [attributes of an svg element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement) you will find that it has got [x](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElementXAttribute) and [y](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElementYAttribute) attributes, but in both cases it says that

> Has no meaning or effect on outermost svg elements

It makes sense though because x and y would only be defined relative to the parent svg element. How to set the position of the top on then?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Show some code!

Comment: To change the position of the `SVG` container itself, you can use CSS or inline `style` rules. For example: `svg { position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the outermost element just like any other DOM element.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", "100").attr("height", "100").style("border", "1px solid black");
```

```css
svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```